# Inotifywait doesn't run command

Tags: bash, inotify, stylus

I have a basic inotifywait script called watch.sh and a few files ending in .styl in the same directory. Here's the script, that catches the changes, but doesn't execute the code within the do/done

I init it like `sh watch.sh` and here's the script

```
#!/bin/sh

while inotifywait -m -o ./log.txt -e modify ./*.styl; do
  stylus -c %f
done
```

I tried having `echo "hi"` within the exec portion but nothing executes

Comment: Wow, I wish I found that earlier. Do you know how I could watch coffeescript + stylus files at the same time?

Comment: Something like `coffee -o lib -cw src` along with `stylus -o css -w stylus` should work fine.

Comment: That's pretty cool, but I'm noticing this issue with the -w in stylus that after the fifth or so compile it compiles a blank .css file requiring me to restart it which is pretty annoying

Comment: If so, you might want to report a bug, but be warned that TJ (stylus' author) doesn't take much interest in the `watch` option.

Comment: Well then I'll try to find a working inotifywait solution that can watch stylus & coffee files simultaneously because I noticed only 1 watch command can be running at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is with the `-m` option for `inotifywait`. This causes the command to never exit. Since `while` checks the exit status of a command, the command must exit in order to continue execution of the loop.

Here is the description of `-m` from the manpage:

```
Instead of exiting  after  receiving  a  single  event,  execute
indefinitely.   The default behaviour is to exit after the first
event occurs.
```

Removing the `-m` option should resolve your issues:

```
while inotifywait -o ./log.txt -e modify ./*.styl; do
  stylus -c %f
done
```

Comment: that solved the problem thanks. A minor issue, %f is not returning the file name but the actual character '%f'. How can I get that working. I've tried adding --format '%w' and echoing %w and/or $file but nothing is returning file. I'd like to recompile any file ending in .styl on save

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while K=`inotifywait -o ./log.txt --format %f -e modify ./*.styl`; 
do 
   stylus -c $K;
done
```